# Find attributes in string with REGEX C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the follow input:

> Pontos: 450; Linhas: 446;  X mínimo: 554625; Y mínimo: 9170625;  Tamanho da célula: 125m;  Projecao: "SAD69   UTM zone 23S";   Dummy: 99999;  X=UTM Este SAD69 Zona 23S;  Y=UTM Norte SAD69 Zona 23S;  gD_FOURIER_0=Gravidade Vertical Fourier, sem correção de terreno;  gD_FOURIER_2p1=Gravidade Vertical Fourier, para correção de terreno com densidade 2.1 g cm³;  GDD_FOURIER_0=Gradiente GDD Fourier, sem correção de terreno.  GDD_FOURIER_2p1=Gradiente GDD Fourier, para correção de terreno com densidade 2.1 g cm³;  gD_FOURIER_2p1_Conformed=Gravidade Vertical Fourier, para correção de terreno com densidade 2.1g cm³, corformado ao modelo DNSC08;

I want to find all attributes `{any}={any};`. I tried with the follow code:

```
string pattern = @"(.*)=(.*);";
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
```

But without success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to be more precise than `{any}`.

What you probably want for the part before the equals sign is "anything except whitespace". That's `\S+` in regex.

And after the equals sign, you probably what "anything except a semicolon". That's `[^;]+`.

```
string pattern = @"(\S+)=([^;]+);";
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kQ3dB3/1).

Comment: Why not `\w+=[^;]+` ? I mean, why `\S+` ?

Comment: Do we know for certain that only letters/digits/underscores will occur there? Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: Right you are, no we don't.

Comment: Besides, just read your profile recently, what about this MBA programme (gibt es das noch?).

Comment: @Jan: Oh ja: https://www.hs-neu-ulm.de/weiterbildung/mba-bwl-fuer-aerzte/ Kann ich nur empfehlen :)

Comment: Na ja, ich bin Psychiater, ich schaue es mir also mal an.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just use:

```
(?P<key>\w+)=(?P<value>[^;]+)
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kQ0wE5/2).

Answer (score 0):

You made it too eager:

```
(.*?)=(.*?);
```

any better?

Edit -> i have forgotten the ';'

Edit2:

```
(.*?)(:|=)(.*?);/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/nY6lS0/1

Comment: Did you test this? The second group will always be empty, and the first group will likely match far too much.

Comment: I have, it worked... Only it depends on the separator... here it is '=', you can use ':', but it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
/([^\s]+?)=(.+?);/g
```

In C#:

```
string pattern = @"([^\s]+?)=(.+?);";
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
```